# Getting fields that take less than certain distinct values

Tags: sql, hive

IF I have data with two columns feature and feature_value, just like the example data set below

```
feature   feature_value
  X           1
  X           1
  X           2
  Y           7
  Y           8
  Y           9
  Z           100
```

and I want to get only feature,feature_value columns for features that have less than 3 distinct values (in this case only columns having X and Z), what is the efficient way to do it? Using Count(Distinct) and applying the where condition or is there any faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that this answer uses generic SQL, and since your question isn't clear as to why you'd only get the "X" and "Y" records when you want those that appear 3 or less,  I've also taken the liberty of understanding your answer to mean you're looking only for the `feature`s that appear less than three times in the `feature` column, per your question saying you're looking for "columns [sic] for features that have less than 3 distinct values."  If you meant *3 or more*, you can easily adjust that in the below subquery by changing `<` to `>=`.

Subquery to `GROUP BY` `feature` and get the count, then select only those records.

```sql
SELECT * FROM my WHERE feature IN
(SELECT feature
FROM my
GROUP BY feature
HAVING COUNT(*) < 3)
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/29c05/1

Comment: Oh, so do you mean fewer than three distinct values in `feature_value`?

Comment: Yes three distinct value in feature_value

Comment: How does the DISTINCT feature help? I should use feature_value right?

Comment: Sorry, you're right--I forgot to update the code from the SQLFiddle.  You do not need the `DISTINCT`.